Using FindWithTag to set object false doesn't work
I used to code GameObject.FindWithTag("Stickman").SetActive(false);
to set the Stickman object with the tag to false but it doesn't work. This is inside a function which activates when a button is clicked and it doesn't work. The error message says that Object reference not set to an instance of a object.
I tried a lot of things but nothing worked.

then it didnt find it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
